# Rshiny: How can I call my JS authentication function such that the Rshiny app can consume the result?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

So I have an Rshiny application set to publish on server, but we need an API authentication token to ensure a given user has access. The Authentication process is handled in JS tags outside of the app, while the actual Rshiny process is held in an iFrame on the page.

I have the js script saved externally in a www/ subdirectory packaged with the app. The JS script queries a value in localStorage to determine the userID, and pings the API validation with this token to determine access. It looks like this (fetch is a custom function that queries local storage to set the auth value).

```
/**
 * This Fn ! using to vaidate the user login access
 * @param none
 */
(function validateUserLoginInfo() {
    console.log("Sending user acess");
    var url = `https://authentication-url.com/isAuthy `;
    fetch(url, { method: 'GET' }, function (response) {
        if (response) {
            // user validation is Successfully done
            // $("#userValidated").val("Yes");
        } else {
            //invalid user access/login failure
            //Shiny.setInputValue("userValidated","No")
            // $("#userValidated").val("No");
        }
    });
})(); // => self executing Fn !
```

What I'm essentially trying to do is run this JS function such that a success yields an input passed into the Rshiny server environment, e.g. input$isUserValidated, so I can route the app processes and alert the instance that the user does not have access. I have it setup such that the "Welcome" page text changes based on this validation response, and the actual tabs with analysis are subsequently hidden from the instance.

In the `if (response) else` calls in the JS function, the commented out lines are the attempts I've made to pass the response to the server environment, but these haven't worked. And I believe the way I'm calling this function from the application is working, but I'm not sure if the function validateUserLoginInfo is actually working.

So I can break down my confusion into two steps really

1. After sourcing the script, either via `tags$head(tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "www/authenticateUser.js"))`or `includeScript('www/authenticateUser.js')` how can I run the actual `validateUserLoginInfo()` function from the r server? Or is it already run automatically on app load?
2. Upon calling `validateUserLoginInfo()`, how can I pass the response from that call such that the R server can consume it?

Here's a hopefully simple app that captures what I'm looking for. The "authenticateUser.js" function can be considered a function that returns a simple "Yes" or "No", and I'm merely trying to access that answer from the R server.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  includeScript('www/authenticateUser.js')
  textOutput('authed'),
)
server <- function(input,output,session){
  output$authed <- renderText({
    # No clue which one of these works; none have worked for me so far
    response <- input$userValidated
    response2 <- validateUserLoginInfo()
    response3 <- shinyjs::js$validateUserLoginInfo()
    return(c(response,response2,response3))
  })
}
```

I've looked far and wide for answers and can't seem to find anything that gets at what I need to accomplish here. Sending alerts or onClick events from JS <-> Shiny seems to be what most people use JS for w.r.t. Rshiny. So any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Shiny server, try wrapping the output of `renderText` inside an `observeEvent` that runs when the value `userValidated` changes.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$userValidated, {
    output$auth <- renderText({
       input$userValidated
    })
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
}
```

In the js function `validateuserLoginInfo`, use `response.ok` to evaluate the status of the request and set the value of `userValidated` accordingly.

I am not sure what information you need to send with the request, so here is an example that demonstrates the concepts. In the example, I wrote a short request that evaluates if the `RStudio` and `RStudi` are valid GitHub users (the second url will fail when used in the request).

```r
library(shiny)

# js
js <- '
// validate user (this will run on page load)
(function validateUserLoginInfo() {
    console.log("Sending user acess");

    // set url (using github API as a generic example; test each url)
    //var url = "https://api.github.com/users/rstudio" // this will pass
    var url = "https://api.github.com/users/rstudi" // this will fail

    // create a new request
    fetch(url, {method: "GET"})
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(response.status);
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {

        // set shiny input as true
        Shiny.setInputValue("userValidated", JSON.stringify(true));

    }).catch((error) => {

        // set input as false + log error
        Shiny.setInputValue("userValidated", JSON.stringify(false));
        console.log(error);
    });

})();
'

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("authed"),
  tags$script(HTML(js))
)

# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # run when change
    observeEvent(input$userValidated, {
        response <- jsonlite::fromJSON(input$userValidated)
        output$authed <- renderPrint({
            response
        })
    }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
}

# app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```